# Specify value-type for wildcard in string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get some information with the `Get-Counter` method in PowerShell.
When I tried to get the actual processor frequency, I noticed that I get multiple values because there are multiple instances.
`_total` the overall frequency (will ever be 0), 
`0,_total` the overall frequency of the first processor (also ever 0)
and `0,0` up to `0,3` for each core.
To get the information I use:

```
(Get-Counter "\Prozessorinformationen(*)\Prozessorfrequenz").countersamples
```

The wildcard specifies for which instance/-s the information is fetched (in this case all)

`Path                                                      InstanceName CookedValue
----                                                      ------------ -----------
\\mypc\prozessorinformationen(_total)\prozessorfrequenz   _total                 0
\\mypc\prozessorinformationen(0,_total)\prozessorfrequenz 0,_total               0
\\mypc\prozessorinformationen(0,3)\prozessorfrequenz      0,3                 2601
\\mypc\prozessorinformationen(0,2)\prozessorfrequenz      0,2                 2601
\\mypc\prozessorinformationen(0,1)\prozessorfrequenz      0,1                 2601
\\mypc\prozessorinformationen(0,0)\prozessorfrequenz      0,0                 2601`

Now I wanted only the results for the single cores. In this special case I could use `0,?` to get the expected result, but if I've (just theoretically) 100000 cores, the number of cores has as much characters as '_total'.

Finally, what i want to know, is it possible to specify a wildcard in a string to accept only values of a specified type (like in this case 'digit'), or do i have to pipe and filter the result?

I tried to use `[0-9]` but this didn't work

Comment: The Performance Counter api doesn't support the full range of wildcard characters that PowerShell support internally, `[0-9]` is not supported for example. Easiest way it to just filter the counter samples in PowerShell with `Where-Object Path -ne '*_total*'`

Comment: Ok, thats a pity. I hoped for a smarter way. But thanks.

Another option would be `Where-Object instancename -match "0,\d"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Please post it as an answer :)